# Boost serialization: safe to ignore warning?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

I started to use boost's serialization code to write data to a binary stream. I get the following warnings which could be disabled (`D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`) but I wonder if it is safe to do so? How can I get more specific information which code of mine causes the warning? I only know the .cpp file.

This is the output from Visual Studio 2008:

```
4>g:\winlib\boost\1_42_0\boost/archive/basic_binary_iprimitive.hpp(162) : warng C4996: 'std::basic_streambuf<_Elem,_Traits>::sgetn': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'
4>        with
4>        [
4>            _Elem=char,
4>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
4>        ]
4>        E:\Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\streambuf(121) : see declaration of 'std::basic_streambuf<_Elem,_Traits>::sgetn'
4>        with
4>        [
4>            _Elem=char,
4>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
4>        ]
4>        g:\winlib\boost\1_42_0\boost/archive/basic_binary_iprimitive.hpp(152) : while compiling class template member function 'void boost::archive::basic_binary_iprimitive<Archive,Elem,Tr>::load_binary(void *,size_t)'
4>        with
4>        [
4>            Archive=boost::archive::naked_binary_iarchive,
4>            Elem=char,
4>            Tr=std::char_traits<char>
4>        ]
4>        g:\winlib\boost\1_42_0\boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp(107) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::basic_binary_iprimitive<Archive,Elem,Tr>::load<T>(T &)' being compiled
4>        with
4>        [
4>            Archive=boost::archive::naked_binary_iarchive,
4>            Elem=char,
4>            Tr=std::char_traits<char>,
4>            T=unsigned char
4>        ]
4>        g:\winlib\boost\1_42_0\boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp(356) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::load_access::load_primitive<Archive,T>(Archive &,T &)' being compiled
4>        with
4>        [
4>            Archive=boost::archive::naked_binary_iarchive,
4>            T=unsigned char
4>        ]
4>        g:\winlib\boost\1_42_0\boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp(433) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::detail::load_non_pointer_type<Archive>::load_primitive::invoke<T>(Archive &,T &)' being compiled
4>        with
4>        [
4>            Archive=boost::archive::naked_binary_iarchive,
4>            T=unsigned char
4>        ]
4>        g:\winlib\boost\1_42_0\boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp(580) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::detail::load_non_pointer_type<Archive>::invoke<T>(Archive &,T &)' being compiled
4>        with
4>        [
4>            Archive=boost::archive::naked_binary_iarchive,
4>            T=unsigned char
4>        ]
4>        g:\winlib\boost\1_42_0\boost/archive/detail/common_iarchive.hpp(68) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::load<Archive,T>(Archive &,T &)' being compiled
4>        with
4>        [
4>            Archive=boost::archive::naked_binary_iarchive,
4>            T=unsigned char
4>        ]
4>        g:\winlib\boost\1_42_0\boost/archive/basic_binary_iarchive.hpp(67) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::detail::common_iarchive<Archive>::load_override<T>(T &,int)' being compiled
4>        with
4>        [
4>            Archive=boost::archive::naked_binary_iarchive,
4>            T=unsigned char
4>        ]
4>        g:\winlib\boost\1_42_0\boost/archive/binary_iarchive_impl.hpp(50) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::basic_binary_iarchive<Archive>::load_override<T>(T &,int)' being compiled
4>        with
4>        [
4>            Archive=boost::archive::naked_binary_iarchive,
4>            T=unsigned char
4>        ]
4>        g:\winlib\boost\1_42_0\boost/archive/detail/interface_iarchive.hpp(61) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::binary_iarchive_impl<Archive,Elem,Tr>::load_override<T>(T &,int)' being compiled
4>        with
4>        [
4>            Archive=boost::archive::naked_binary_iarchive,
4>            Elem=char,
4>            Tr=std::char_traits<char>,
4>            T=unsigned char
4>        ]
4>        g:\winlib\boost\1_42_0\boost/archive/basic_binary_iarchive.hpp(77) : see reference to function template instantiation 'Archive &boost::archive::detail::interface_iarchive<Archive>::operator >><unsigned char>(T &)' being compiled
4>        with
4>        [
4>            Archive=boost::archive::naked_binary_iarchive,
4>            T=unsigned char
4>        ]
4>        g:\winlib\boost\1_42_0\boost/archive/basic_binary_iarchive.hpp(74) : while compiling class template member function 'void boost::archive::basic_binary_iarchive<Archive>::load_override(boost::archive::version_type &,int)'
4>        with
4>        [
4>            Archive=boost::archive::naked_binary_iarchive
4>        ]
4>        g:\winlib\boost\1_42_0\boost/archive/binary_iarchive_impl.hpp(36) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::archive::basic_binary_iarchive<Archive>' being compiled
4>        with
4>        [
4>            Archive=boost::archive::naked_binary_iarchive
4>        ]
4>        g:\winlib\boost\1_42_0\boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp(42) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::archive::binary_iarchive_impl<Archive,Elem,Tr>' being compiled
4>        with
4>        [
4>            Archive=boost::archive::naked_binary_iarchive,
4>            Elem=char,
4>            Tr=std::char_traits<char>
4>        ]
4>g:\winlib\boost\1_42_0\boost/archive/basic_binary_iprimitive.hpp(176) : warning C4996: 'std::basic_streambuf<_Elem,_Traits>::sgetn': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'
4>        with
4>        [
4>            _Elem=char,
4>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
4>        ]
4>        E:\Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\streambuf(121) : see declaration of 'std::basic_streambuf<_Elem,_Traits>::sgetn'
4>        with
4>        [
4>            _Elem=char,
4>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
4>        ]
4>g:\winlib\boost\1_42_0\boost/archive/basic_binary_iprimitive.hpp(162) : warning C4996: 'std::basic_streambuf<_Elem,_Traits>::sgetn': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'
4>        with
4>        [
4>            _Elem=char,
4>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
4>        ]
4>        E:\Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\streambuf(121) : see declaration of 'std::basic_streambuf<_Elem,_Traits>::sgetn'
4>        with
4>        [
4>            _Elem=char,
4>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
4>        ]
4>        g:\winlib\boost\1_42_0\boost/archive/basic_binary_iprimitive.hpp(152) : while compiling class template member function 'void boost::archive::basic_binary_iprimitive<Archive,Elem,Tr>::load_binary(void *,size_t)'
4>        with
4>        [
4>            Archive=boost::archive::binary_iarchive,
4>            Elem=char,
4>            Tr=std::char_traits<char>
4>        ]
4>        g:\winlib\boost\1_42_0\boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp(107) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::basic_binary_iprimitive<Archive,Elem,Tr>::load<T>(T &)' being compiled
4>        with
4>        [
4>            Archive=boost::archive::binary_iarchive,
4>            Elem=char,
4>            Tr=std::char_traits<char>,
4>            T=unsigned char
4>        ]
4>        g:\winlib\boost\1_42_0\boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp(356) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::load_access::load_primitive<Archive,T>(Archive &,T &)' being compiled
4>        with
4>        [
4>            Archive=boost::archive::binary_iarchive,
4>            T=unsigned char
4>        ]
4>        g:\winlib\boost\1_42_0\boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp(433) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::detail::load_non_pointer_type<Archive>::load_primitive::invoke<T>(Archive &,T &)' being compiled
4>        with
4>        [
4>            Archive=boost::archive::binary_iarchive,
4>            T=unsigned char
4>        ]
4>        g:\winlib\boost\1_42_0\boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp(580) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::detail::load_non_pointer_type<Archive>::invoke<T>(Archive &,T &)' being compiled
4>        with
4>        [
4>            Archive=boost::archive::binary_iarchive,
4>            T=unsigned char
4>        ]
4>        g:\winlib\boost\1_42_0\boost/archive/detail/common_iarchive.hpp(68) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::load<Archive,T>(Archive &,T &)' being compiled
4>        with
4>        [
4>            Archive=boost::archive::binary_iarchive,
4>            T=unsigned char
4>        ]
4>        g:\winlib\boost\1_42_0\boost/archive/basic_binary_iarchive.hpp(67) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::detail::common_iarchive<Archive>::load_override<T>(T &,int)' being compiled
4>        with
4>        [
4>            Archive=boost::archive::binary_iarchive,
4>            T=unsigned char
4>        ]
4>        g:\winlib\boost\1_42_0\boost/archive/binary_iarchive_impl.hpp(50) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::basic_binary_iarchive<Archive>::load_override<T>(T &,int)' being compiled
4>        with
4>        [
4>            Archive=boost::archive::binary_iarchive,
4>            T=unsigned char
4>        ]
4>        g:\winlib\boost\1_42_0\boost/archive/detail/interface_iarchive.hpp(61) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::binary_iarchive_impl<Archive,Elem,Tr>::load_override<T>(T &,int)' being compiled
4>        with
4>        [
4>            Archive=boost::archive::binary_iarchive,
4>            Elem=char,
4>            Tr=std::char_traits<char>,
4>            T=unsigned char
4>        ]
4>        g:\winlib\boost\1_42_0\boost/archive/basic_binary_iarchive.hpp(77) : see reference to function template instantiation 'Archive &boost::archive::detail::interface_iarchive<Archive>::operator >><unsigned char>(T &)' being compiled
4>        with
4>        [
4>            Archive=boost::archive::binary_iarchive,
4>            T=unsigned char
4>        ]
4>        g:\winlib\boost\1_42_0\boost/archive/basic_binary_iarchive.hpp(74) : while compiling class template member function 'void boost::archive::basic_binary_iarchive<Archive>::load_override(boost::archive::version_type &,int)'
4>        with
4>        [
4>            Archive=boost::archive::binary_iarchive
4>        ]
4>        g:\winlib\boost\1_42_0\boost/archive/binary_iarchive_impl.hpp(36) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::archive::basic_binary_iarchive<Archive>' being compiled
4>        with
4>        [
4>            Archive=boost::archive::binary_iarchive
4>        ]
4>        g:\winlib\boost\1_42_0\boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp(76) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::archive::binary_iarchive_impl<Archive,Elem,Tr>' being compiled
4>        with
4>        [
4>            Archive=boost::archive::binary_iarchive,
4>            Elem=char,
4>            Tr=std::char_traits<char>
4>        ]
4>g:\winlib\boost\1_42_0\boost/archive/basic_binary_iprimitive.hpp(176) : warning C4996: 'std::basic_streambuf<_Elem,_Traits>::sgetn': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'
4>        with
4>        [
4>            _Elem=char,
4>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
4>        ]
4>        E:\Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\streambuf(121) : see declaration of 'std::basic_streambuf<_Elem,_Traits>::sgetn'
4>        with
4>        [
4>            _Elem=char,
4>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
4>        ]
```

Thanks!

Comment: this is from VS output. I have a couple of projects in my solution and it is the output from compiling project 4. (Helpful in parallel compilation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you trust Boost not to pass out-of-range parameters, you can disable the warnings.

Microsoft has proposed a set of new "more secure" functions for the C library,

http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1225.pdf

and are warning everyone who uses the old ones.

You could perhaps also try a newer Boost library? The lastest is 1.46.1

Comment: Except that the function the compiler is complaining about isn't C, but C++, and it's perfectly safe (or at least as safe as anything using char* can be).

Answer (score 0):

If your project is going to be compiled only using the Visual Studio you can replace call to **sgetn** (from the line of warning) on **[_Sgetn_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985925%28VS.80%29.aspx)** and duplicate the last parameter of the initial call. That way you will transform call into the safe one.

Or you can go with patch provided below, it applies **[_Sgetn_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985925%28VS.80%29.aspx)** for VC 8.0 and higher, but leaves **sgetn** for all other compilers.

```
Index: basic_binary_iprimitive.hpp
===================================================================

@@ -143,6 +143,11 @@
     void
     load_binary(void *address, std::size_t count);
 };
+#if defined(_MSC_VER) && (_MSC_VER >= 1400) //VC 8.0 +
+#   define BOOST_sgetn_safe( buf, count ) _Sgetn_s( buf, count, count )
+#else 
+#   define BOOST_sgetn_safe( buf, count ) sgetn( buf, count )
+#endif

 template<class Archive, class Elem, class Tr>
 inline void
@@ -157,6 +162,7 @@
     );
     std::streamsize s = static_cast<std::streamsize>(count / sizeof(Elem));
-    std::streamsize scount = m_sb.sgetn(
+    std::streamsize scount = m_sb.BOOST_sgetn_safe(
         static_cast<Elem *>(address), 
         s
     );
@@ -173,7 +179,7 @@
 //                archive_exception(archive_exception::stream_error)
 //        );
         Elem t;
-        scount = m_sb.sgetn(& t, 1);
+        scount = m_sb.BOOST_sgetn_safe(& t, 1);
         if(scount != 1)
             boost::serialization::throw_exception(
                 archive_exception(archive_exception::input_stream_error)
@@ -181,6 +187,7 @@
         std::memcpy(static_cast<char*>(address) + (count - s), &t, s);
     }
 }
+#undef BOOST_sgetn_safe

 } // namespace archive
 } // namespace boost
```

Answer (score 0):

Boost documentation admits that there are many warnings that are safe to ignore.  I removed irritating warning messages from my console in Visual Studio 2008 by adding the following to my code:

```
#pragma warning(disable:4099)
```